# probability and programming simulation

Tags: java, statistics

I'm having some trouble understanding the following result.

I want to know if the following code is actually correct. It stumps me - but that could be due to me misunderstanding the probability involved.

The code should speak for itself, but to clarify the 'real world' simulation represents 2 people flipping a coin. When you lose you pay 1 dollar, when you win you win a dollar. An even sum game!

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int i=0;
   for (int x = 0; x<1000000; x++) {
      if (rnd.nextBoolean())  i+=1; 
      else  i-=1; 
    }
    System.out.println(i);
 }
```

When I run this however I get huge swings! Whilst I would expect a large sample like this to converge to 0, I'm seeing +-4000

Not only that but increasing the sample size seems to only make the swings higher.

Am I misusing the random function ? :P

Comment: How are you getting to +/- 4000?  Are you saying that's the sample standard deviation or just the maximum range of values you're seeing.  If it's the maximum range of values, how many times did you run the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're good. The thing to look at is the ratio of the swing to your sample.

4000 out of 1000000 for example is 0.4%

If you increase the sample size, you should expect that ratio to go down.

Comment: You are correct. The Law of large numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers only states that the relative numbers will converge, while the absolute difference resembles a random walk.

Comment: I recall reading that the value obtained by this process will generally be off by ln(flips). I can't find anything pertaining to this anymore...

Comment: The variance of the binomial distribution is n*p*(1-p) which works out to a standard deviation of 500 in the OP's case.  This makes valueS that are positive or minus 4000 pretty large outliers.

Comment: I would expect something with a square. Using the Normal Distribution approximation of the Binomial distribution, I'd say around 68% will be less than 0.5*sqrt(n) away from average. (So in this case one would expect i to be < 0.5 * sqrt(n) in around 70% of the cases, or less than 3/2*sqrt(n) in 99.7% of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

The results of your experiment should follow a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  If the
number of trials is N, and the probability of success p=1/2, then the
number of successes N_success (for large enough N) should have a mean of approximately Np,
and standard deviation sqrt(N*p*(1-p)).

You're actually tracking K = (N_success - N_fail).  So N_success = N/2 + K/2.
With 1,000,000 trials and K=4000, we get N_success = 502000. The expected
value is 500000, with standard deviation sqrt(250000) = 500. The difference 
between the observed and expected values of N_success is 2000, or about 4 sigma.
That's significant enough to question whether the random number generator is
biased.  On the other hand, if you're running this test thousands of times, 
you'd expect a few outliers of this magnitude, and you seem to be seeing both
positive and negative values, so in the long run maybe things are OK after all.

Answer (score 1):

You are simulating a [one-dimensional random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk). Basically, imagine yourself standing on a line of integers. You begin at point `i=0`. With equal probability you take a step to the right or the left.

The random walk has a few cool properties and you've touched on my favourite:

- Starting at point `i=0`, as N gets larger, the probability that you will return to that point approaches 1. As you point out - a zero sum game.
- However, the expected time it will take you to return there tends to infinity. As you notice, you get some very large swings.

Since the average value should be 0 and the variance of *N* moves is *N*, then you would expect 95% of your simulations to **end** in the region: (- 1.96, 1.96)*N^(0.5).